# React native detect screen rotation

Tags: react-native, screen-orientation, drawer

I'm using onLayout to detect screen orientation and it's working fine inside my root view, but when I implemented inside the drawer it didn't work, any reason why this happens ?

code :

```
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer'
  ...
onLayout(e) {
   console.log('onLayout');
}
<Drawer  onLayout={this.onLayout}
```

It didn't log any thing when orientation changed!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Drawer component doesn't take `onLayout` as a prop. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/blob/cffbeb37cd5556b45076158c3158ee3562e16a59/index.js#L519) that the rendered `View` does use `onLayout`, but it's not pulling from something like `this.props.onLayout`.

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking to do, but maybe [this issue](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/issues/240) will help you. As it shows, you can pass a function into `openDrawerOffset` instead of an integer or a ratio in order to be a little more dynamic with how you set your offset:

```
openDrawerOffset={(viewport) => {
    if (viewport.width < 400) {
        return viewport.width * 0.1;
    }
    return viewport.width - 400;
}}
```

You might also benefit from the [Event handlers](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer#event-handlers) that react-native-drawer has to offer.